# On the sum of the logarithms of primes.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $x$ be an integer. It is known that $\sum_{p\leq x}  \log p = O(x)$, and i think this is equivalent to the Prime Number Theorem.
                                                                      As a mere *prospective* undergraduate with only a minimal understanding of analytic number theory, i'm curiously wondering if there exists an analogous formula for $\sum_{p\leq x} \log(p-1)$ ?

Comment: In this  context,  I  think that $\log(p-1)$ and $\log p$ are of the same size.

Comment: They differ by roughly $\sum \frac1p\approx\log\log x$

Comment: @Michael, any reference or proof for that result would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: After a little research on the question in Martin Klazar's *Introdution To Number Theory*, i found the same answer that MichaeI provided below, but i was left with another question again, which i have posted here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1632689/305659. Please may you kindly consider it also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log(p-1)=\log(p)+\log(1-\frac1p)\approx\log(p)-\frac1p$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes